# different Application signature issue android?

Tags: java, android, installation, uninstallation

In my project i have created an application that has being modified later now when i try to install new application it ask for **full uninstall of the application.** of previous application but i can not do the same coz i am to **reuse the data left by the previous application** not can i fix the **different application signatures.** issue can i get install it to device without unistallation.

> `I'm to retain application data`

```
[2012-05-23 19:09:56 - iCam] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2012-05-23 19:09:56 - iCam] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2012-05-23 19:09:56 - iCam] Please execute 'adb uninstall iCam.Cam' in a shell.
[2012-05-23 19:09:56 - iCam] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: What is your question? How to fix "different application signatures"?

Comment: Sign the apk with the key you used to sign the previous apk.

Comment: we didn't did any think how to find the key and signature i have no idea regarding this

Comment: @Rajesh : yes something like this which will enable me to install the new application by retaining the old application

Comment: A few questions: How was this APK created previously - with debug certificate or using self signed certificate? How are you creating it now? Is the same computer and user account used to create the APK?

Comment: may I know how the remote user will install. thru 3rd part or cmd.

Comment: @haibison : what i just want to say ; LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Fortunately I had a "to-file" backup functionality in this app. You need the same signature. Do you use the Debug-Keystore? That's not a good idea for real world usage. you need to use the same Debug-Key the original creator used.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install application with the same signature as the one which is already on the device.

You will need to determine how the application was installed on the device. You have at least two options:

- default debug signing key from Eclipse was used (key `androiddebugkey` in keystore `~/.android/debug.keystore`)
- other keystore was used during the File->Export...

If you used binary generated in the `bin` directory (or installed apk directly from Eclipse) the default keystore was used and to create compatible apk you need to locate same file which was at this location  when creating first apk: `~/.android/debug.keystore`. Then use `File->Export...` and choose this file. Enter `android` password, choose `androiddebugkey` and enter `android` password again. Finally choose destination apk name and click `Finish`.

If finding previous signing key is not possible you can try to:

- backup the application data
- uninstall the application
- install application with different signature (now it succeeds)
- install back application data

Backup and restore of application data can be done using TitaniumBackup app. It may require rooted device.

Comment: i know this as message said but where to find signature no idea regarding this

Comment: @PhotonCriticalFatalError_ How did you install the first application?

Comment: just i copied apk from bin and delievered to client simply like that

Comment: @PhotonCriticalFatalError_, I updated my answer. You just need to find `debug.keystore` file you previously used.

Comment: sorry dude unfortunately the application was released on debug mode

Comment: @PhotonCriticalFatalError_ I understand, but do you have this file?

Comment: no that was developed one of my senior programmers and i don't know any thing what they did now i'm launching new version that is not allowed to install over it without uninstallation

Comment: @PhotonCriticalFatalError_, try to contact that programmer (who I assume generated the installed apk) to send you this file or the keystore he used during export.

Comment: i've the whole code but when i created from the same code it gave me this warning

Comment: @PhotonCriticalFatalError_, keystore is not part of the code (and never should) it resides in different directory. On linux it sits in the home directory in `.android/debug.keystore`, but it is usually used from custom location. If the developer who produced the apk didn't explicitly used other keystore it almost certainly must be `.android/debug.keystore`.

Comment: Excellent, this saved my day! Just a note that if you are developing across multiple machines you can copy the `~/.android/debug.keystore` onto all machines and your development device will work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

//install thru command prompt by using -r which reinstall by keeping its data

```
adb install -r ./yourfolder/MyCam.apk
```

//adb install options

```
adb install [-l] [-r] [-s] <file> - push this package file to the device and install it
                                 ('-l' means forward-lock the app)
                                 ('-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data)
                                 ('-s' means install on SD card instead of internal storage)
```

Comment: thanks dude but i am to create this new app which will be used by my user at remote location is there any process to add some code to enable this in application

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same signature you signed your last build with.  If you reset the debug signature in Eclipse or if you signed the app with a new release key, then you can't update.  The only way to fix this is to use the same key you signed it with last time AFAIK.

In DDMS however, you may be able to pull the data from the SD card, uninstall the app, reinstall, then put the data back.  I've never tried this, but I think this may be your only option.

Comment: you can do this with emulator not for device you need root access for this but i have deivce a remote site

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but you're going to have to sign it with the last key signature you had.  Android has mechanisms in place to prevent what you're trying to do so people with malicious intent can't access data of other applications by overwriting it.